# Parsing txt file to rows and columns in PHP

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and have done some light web design but am trying to parse a text file into row and columns and I just cannot get it to return the correct format. 
Here is my php file

```
<?php
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/config/Configfiles/showpeers/output.txt');
$txt_file = str_replace('/\s+/', '_', $txt_file);
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
//array_shift($rows);

foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{

    //get row data
    $row_data = explode('_', $data);

    $info[$row]['Name/username']           = $row_data[0];
    $info[$row]['Host']         = $row_data[1];
    $info[$row]['Dyn']  = $row_data[2];
    $info[$row]['Forceport']       = $row_data[3];
    $info[$row]['Comedia']       = $row_data[4];
    $info[$row]['ACL']       = $row_data[4];
    $info[$row]['Port']       = $row_data[4];
    $info[$row]['Status']       = $row_data[7];
    $info[$row]['Description']       = $row_data[8];

    //display data
    echo ' PEER: ' . $info[$row]['Name/username'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Host: ' . $info[$row]['Host'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Dyn: ' . $info[$row]['Dyn'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Forceport: ' . $info[$row]['Forceport'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Comedia: ' . $info[$row]['Comedia'] . '<br />';
    echo ' ACL: ' . $info[$row]['ACL'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Port: ' . $info[$row]['Port'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Status: ' . $info[$row]['Status'] . '<br />';
    echo ' Description: ' . $info[$row]['Description'] . '<br />';

       echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

The TXT file is

Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
1001                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1002                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1003                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1401/1401                 192.168.21.94                            D  Auto (No)  No             58790    OK (50 ms)
1402                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1403                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1404                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1405                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1406                      (Unspecified)                            D  Yes        Yes            0        Unmonitored
1407                      (Unspecified)                            D  Yes        Yes            0        Unmonitored
1408                      (Unspecified)                            D  Yes        Yes            0        Unmonitored
1409                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1410                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1411                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1412                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1413                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1414                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1415                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
1420                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
2801                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
2803                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
2805                      (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
MCD_Demo                  192.168.22.37                               Yes        Yes            5060     OK (19 ms)
NCP                       192.168.21.74                               Yes        Yes            5060     UNREACHABLE
STG01                     192.168.27.50                               Yes        Yes            5060     UNREACHABLE
switchvox/switchvox       (Unspecified)                            D  Yes        Yes            0        UNKNOWN
26 sip peers [Monitored: 2 online, 3 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 21 offline]

My output looks like the image below. I am trying to get the rows to populate off spaces but it is not working properly.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You cannot pass a regular expression to `str_replace()`, use `preg_replace()` instead.

Comment: As you seems trying to "inject" word in HTML, I suggest you to have look at "template". concept. This mean writing the HTML code in which you write eg "*NAME*" for people name, "*DATE*"  etc... then you perform a str_replace using the fact str_replace can use array as "search" and as "replace".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I was able to figure it out. Below is the new PHP

```
<?php
$txt_file    = 
file_get_contents('/var/www/html/config/Configfiles/showpeers/output.txt');
$txt_file = preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $txt_file);
$rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
array_shift($rows);
array_pop($rows);
array_pop($rows);

foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
  //get row data
$row_data = explode(' ', $data);

$info[$row]['Name/username']           = $row_data[0];
$info[$row]['Host']         = $row_data[1];
$info[$row]['Dyn']  = $row_data[2];
$info[$row]['Forceport']       = $row_data[3];
$info[$row]['Comedia']       = $row_data[4];
$info[$row]['ACL']       = $row_data[4];
$info[$row]['Port']       = $row_data[4];
$info[$row]['Status']       = $row_data[7];
$info[$row]['Description']       = $row_data[8];

//display data
echo ' PEER: ' . $info[$row]['Name/username'] . '<br />';
echo ' Host: ' . $info[$row]['Host'] . '<br />';
//echo ' Dyn: ' . $info[$row]['Dyn'] . '<br />';
//echo ' Forceport: ' . $info[$row]['Forceport'] . '<br />';
//echo ' Comedia: ' . $info[$row]['Comedia'] . '<br />';
//echo ' ACL: ' . $info[$row]['ACL'] . '<br />';
//echo ' Port: ' . $info[$row]['Port'] . '<br />';
echo ' Status: ' . $info[$row]['Status'] . '<br />';
//echo ' Description: ' . $info[$row]['Description'] . '<br />';

   echo '<br />';
```

}
?>